# How to fix mocking auth error in cakephp 2 and phpunit4 up?

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-2.5

I'm getting `Static method "user" cannot be invoked on mock object` even did not mock `auth->user`.

Im using php7, cakephp2.x and phpunit4+
According to cakephp2 documentation :

```
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html
If you are using PHPUnit 4 or 5, staticExpects() does not exist anymore. Instead, you should insert the necessary data into the session with CakeSession::write('Auth.User', $user) before calling the action.
```

I tried using :

```
$user = [
  'id' => 1,
  'username' => 'mark'
];

CakeSession::write('Auth.User', $user);
```

But when calling :

```
$user = $this->Controller->Auth->user();
```

Im still getting : 
`Static method "user" cannot be invoked on mock object` error

Surely i'm missing something here but I don't know what. could you please help me the correct approach here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running:

- PHP 7.3.9
- CakePHP 2.10.16
- PHPUnit 5.7.27

I solved this by mocking the `Session` and `Auth` component. I'm creating the controller in the tests `setUp` like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class MyIntegrationTestCase extends ControllerTestCase
{
  protected $ctrl;

  public function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    // https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-ControllerTestCase.html#_generate
    $mocks = [
      'components' => [
        'Session',
        'Auth',
      ]
    ];
    $this->ctrl = $this->generate('Quotes', $mocks);

    $user = [
      'id' => 1,
      'username' => 'alistaircol',
    ];
    CakeSession::write('Auth.User', $user);
  }
}
```

Not 100% certain whether you need to mock `Auth` component in your project, but I got 302 without this. Don't know if this is something non-standard in my project.

Also, you might need to run the test with the `--stderr` flag for session to work correctly.

References:

- https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-ControllerTestCase.html#_generate